# Android XMPPTCPConnection - stays connected but not receiving packets

Tags: android, xmpp

I have a XMPPTCPConnection initialised in a Service and I see from the logs that it is alive and stays connected. But after a few mins of inactivity, it does not receive any packet. If I turn off wifi/data, the "ClosedOnError" event gets triggered, showing that the object is indeed alive. Please let me know what I might be doing wrong. Appreciate your help.

This is the part where I set the SSL -
          configBuilder.setCustomSSLContext(sslContext);
          configBuilder.setSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
          XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
          XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptiodDefault(true);

This is the Listener added -
      public void setTextMessageListener()
      {
            XMPPConnection connection = XMPPConnHelper.getXmppConnInstance().getConnection();
            if (null != connection)
            {
                XMPPConnHelper.getXmppConnInstance().addPacketListener(getPacketListener());
            }
      }

```
  private StanzaListener getPacketListener()
  {
      StanzaListener packetListener = new StanzaListener()
      {
            @Override
            public void processPacket(Stanza packet)
            {
                final Message message = (Message) packet;
                final String msgBody = message.getBody();
```

Comment: add some piece of code to identity the problem, have you set packet listeners ??

Comment: Thanks, I have added snippets. Yes, I had set packet listeners, they are getting triggered immediately on connection but not after a few mins of inactivity. I don't have any code to unregister the listener.